# IVP- Has at most one solution

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, fixed-point-theorems

Suppose $f(t, x)$ is nonincreasing with respect to $x$ for all $t \geq  0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that the IVP problem
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
x'(t)=f(t,x) \\
x(t_0)=x_0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
has at most one solution for $t \geq t_0$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are two different solutions. Let $h(t)=(x_1(t)-x_2(t))^2$. Then $h(t)\ge0$ for $t\ge t_0$ and $h(t_0)=0$. Take derivatives and use the equation to get
$$
h'(t)=2(x_1(t)-x_2(t))(f(t,x_1(t))-f(t,x_2(t))).
$$
Use the fact that $f(t,x)$ is non-increasing in $x$ for each $t\ge t_0$ to deduce that $h'(t)\le0$ and that $h$ is non-increasing.

Comment: Hey thank you so much, It make sense! You guys are so quick.

Comment: you mean $(f(t,x_1(t))-f(t,x_2(t)))$

Comment: @NeerajBhauryal hankyou. I have edited the answer.