# How prove this problem admits at most one solution if $f'(x)=g[f(x)]$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

**Question:**

> Let $f(x)$ be a derivartive,if give the  initial conditions
>    and there exsit $g(x)$ be such that
>   $$f'(x)=g[f(x)]$$
>
> Show that: the problem admits at most one solution.

This problem is from when I want deal this problem [How prove $f(x)$ is monotonous , if $f'(x)=g[f(x)]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/812593/how-prove-fx-is-monotonous-if-fx-gfx)

**If we can prove this problem have most one solution, then we can prove $f(x)$ is monotonous, so we can use ODE methods to prove it? Such as this method:  [IVP- Has at most one solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214247/ivp-has-at-most-one-solution?rq=1)

Now can you someone can prove it? Thank you.**

Comment: If $g$ is Lipschitz continuous then you can apply the [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem)

Comment: This $g$ can't such Lipschitz contionuous

Comment: Ok, but showing uniqueness of a non-linear differential equation (without any nice properties on $g$) is usually much harder than the original problem of showing that $f$ is monotone.

Comment: Hello,Do you think this link @user3294068 prove is right? Thank you

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your question. Can you try harder to clarify?

Comment: @math110 I don't think this problem is well posed without more information about the properties of $g$. If $g$ is continuous then his proof has the right idea.

Comment: But I think we can prove this problem .Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is not true in general. Standard counterexample: let $g(x) = \dfrac32x^{1/3}$; then the equation $f'(x)=g(f(x))$ admits infinitely many solutions:

1. $f(x) \equiv 0$
2. $f(x) = \max(x,0)^{3/2}$
3. $f(x) = \max(x-1,0)^{3/2}$

and so on...

---

As mentioned in the comments, the solution is unique if $g$ is locally Lipschitz; for example if $g'$ exists and is continuous.